# bash [[ for numerical comparison?

Tags: bash, if-statement

We have some scripts that do things like

```
e=$?
if [[ $e == 123 ]]; then exit 1; fi
```

They're more complicated than that, it's just an example. My question is using double brackets acceptable to make numerical comparisons this way, is there any disadvantage? I would think it should be double parentheses `if (( $e == 123 ))` but I don't want to go changing a lot of scripts over nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of *key* differences doing it, because `==` checks for exact string equality, but `-eq` evaluates both expressions arithmetically before checking for equality.

```
$ [[ " 1 " -eq 1 ]] && echo equal || echo not
equal

$ (( " 1 " == 1 )) && echo equal || echo not
equal

$ [[ " 1 " = 1 ]] && echo equal || echo not
not
```

Also, the empty string happens to be numerically equal to zero:

```
$ [[ "" -eq 0 ]] && echo equal || echo not
equal
$ [[ "" == 0 ]] && echo equal || echo not
not
```

And a whole other class of differences appears when you bring the comparison operators in - considering `<` vs `-lt`, for instance:

```
$ [[ 2 -lt 10 ]] && echo less || echo not
less
$ (( 2 < 10 )) && echo less || echo not
less
$ [[ 2 < 10 ]] && echo less || echo not
not
```

This is because the string `2` is alphabetically after the string `10` (since `1` comes before `2`), but the number `2` is numerically less than the number `10`.

Credits to the original cross site duplicate, with a few updates [Is there any major difference when comparing a variable as a string or as an int?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143800/112235)

#### The verdict is to use `$((..))` for arithmetic comparisons *strictly* to avoid interpreting the operands as strings.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I have marked your answer as correct